# PHP - SQL - How to create a monthly report in MySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

I have "Sales" Table in my DB, which contains daily product sales.

[image]

1-  How to write query that will fetch records first group by date and then group by product & then populate the table.

2-  Any JQuery plugin to create output like following table.

Required Output be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation function as  sum and group by  date and product

```
select date, product, sum(quantity)
from my_table
group by date, product
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT date as Date, product as Product, SUM(quantity) as Quantity FROM Sales GROUP BY date, product
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select cast(date as date) as 'Date', Product, sum(quantity) as 'Quantity'
from sales 
group by cast(date as date), Product
order by  cast(date as date) asc
```